Big O arithmetic of tangent
I haven't seen any estimation with big O of tangent, I tried to use limit for the proof, however for it's oscillating behaviour I find it hard to prove that $tan(x)\neq O(2^x)$ where x is all real numbers where tangent is defined and what happens if we restrict x to integers only.

From the left of the points $k\cdot\frac \pi 2, k>1, k$ odd, the $\tan$ tends to plus infinity, i.e. in a certain left neighborhood of it will hold $\tan x > 2^{k\cdot\frac \pi 2}>2^x$.

thanks! does restriction to integer have any effect, will we take subsequence of integers for the same neighborhood?

Thanks for the rating. The question boils down to whether there will be a subsequence of natural numbers in a close enough left neighborhood of the $k \cdot\frac \pi 2$. I don't have an answer right now, though I see several possible analyses. I'll write when/if I find an answer.

The restriction to integers completely changes the picture. See my answer.

I saw it, @Emil Jeřábek. Now, as far as I understand, the question at this stage is about relationships $\tan n$ and $2^n$. What is your answer?

I’m confused. What do you mean by “what is your answer”, when you say you “saw it”? My answer is that $\tan n$ is $O(n^{6{.}1})$, possibly even less, hence it is certainly $O(2^n)$, and even much smaller than that.

Your main result is based on the words "if a sufficiently large $n$ is close to" and I think it would be appropriate to more precisely decipher this sentence.

? This is just normal mathematical English. "Sufficiently large $n$ ..." means "there is $n_0$ such that for all $n\ge n_0$" (namely, you have to avoid the finitely many exceptions in the defining property of $\mu$), though this does not really matter, as the statement in the end is asymptotic anyway. And "close to $(2m+1)\frac\pi2$" suggests to zoom in on the odd multiple of $\frac\pi2$ closest to $n$, but this does not matter either, as for all other $m$ the lower bound on the difference holds trivially.

You didn't understand: of course it is completely unnecessary to repeat a well-known phrase, especially interrupting it in the most important place. And replacing the word "close" with the word "zoom", did you answer or explain anything? Usually, when we talk about closeness for a sequence, we mean a certain neighborhood. What you cited is, for example, a neighborhood of plus infinity. But I asked specifically about the phrase "sufficiently large n is close to $(2m+1)\frac \pi 2$" (there is no other such phrase in the text). Do you mean some neighborhood of $(2m+1)\frac \pi 2$? (continued)

(continuation).  In the text of the definition of irrationality measure, the inequality is satisfied for all but finitely many pairs $(p,q)\in\mathbb N^2$, i.e., for a certain neighborhood of infinity $(+\infty, +\infty)$. But I don't immediately see the numerator falling into neighborhood of ​​the denominator. This is exactly what my question is about, if you can, then, as I already wrote, it would be appropriate to explain this to us.

(continuation) Without having a connection between $n$ and $m$, how can you replace $\Omega(m)$ with $\Omega(n)$? I hope I have now explained my question clearly and with this detail your answer will be better.

I haven’t seen your comments until now as you didn’t notify me. This is all sapienti sat, really, but anyway, I have included a bit more details of the calculation.

The question of the behaviour of $\tan n$ for $n\in\mathbb N$ as $n\to\infty$  is rather subtle. The result is that it is polynomially bounded, and conjecturally almost linearly bounded.
The $\tan$ function is $\pi$-periodic, and it is unbounded only near the singularities at $x=(2m+1)\frac\pi2$, $m\in\mathbb Z$, hence we need to (1) estimate the rate of growth of $\tan$ near these points, and (2) analyze how close can $(2m+1)\frac\pi2$ be to an integer $n$.
(1) is easy: the power series expansion of $\tan x$ near $0$ gives
$$\tan x=x+O(x^3)=\Theta(x),\qquad x\to0.$$
Thus, using the identity
$$\tan\bigl((2m+1)\tfrac\pi2-x\bigr)=\frac1{\tan x},$$
we obtain
$$\tag{$*$}\tan x=O\bigl(|x-(2m+1)\tfrac\pi2|^{-1}\bigr),$$
where $m\in\mathbb N$ is such that the distance of $x$ to $(2m+1)\tfrac\pi2$ is minimized, i.e., $m=\lfloor x/\pi\rfloor$.
As for (2), analyzing how close $(2m+1)\frac\pi2$ can be to $n$ for $n,m\in\mathbb N$ amounts to analyzing how close can $\pi$ be approximated by rationals, which is the subject of Diophantine approximation. The number $\pi$ is known to have a finite irrationality measure: this means there is a constant $\mu$ such that
$$\tag{$**$}\left|\frac pq-\pi\right|\ge\frac1{q^\mu}$$
for all but finitely many pairs $(p,q)\in\mathbb N^2$.
The current best bound due to Zeilberger and Zudilin is that we can take
$$\mu\le7{.}103205334137\dots.$$
Now, as a consequence, if $m=\lfloor n/\pi\rfloor$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
\left|n-(2m+1)\frac\pi2\right|=\frac{2m+1}2\left|\pi-\frac{2n}{2m+1}\right|&\ge\frac{2m+1}{2(2m+1)^\mu}=\frac12(2m+1)^{1-\mu}\\
&\ge\frac{\pi^{\mu-1}}{2^\mu}\left(n+\frac\pi 2\right)^{1-\mu},
\end{align*}$$
provided $n$ is sufficiently large so that $(2n,2m+1)$ is not one of the finitely many exceptions $(p,q)$ that fail $(**)$. Thus, using $(*)$,
$$\tan n=O(n^{\mu-1})=O(n^{6{.}1032\dots}),\qquad n\in\mathbb N.$$
It is expected that the irrationality measure of $\pi$ is in fact $2$ (which is the least possible value), thus we can take $\mu$ arbitrarily close to $2$, and $\tan n=O(n^{1+\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon>0$.
Note that by Dirichlet’s approximation theorem, there are infinitely many pairs $(p,q)\in\mathbb N^2$ such that
$$\left|\pi-\frac pq\right|\le\frac1{q^2},$$
and one can arrange a similar bound already with even $p$ and odd $q$, as in the expression for $\bigl|n-(2m+1)\frac\pi2\bigr|$ above. Thus, we get the lower bound
$$\tan n\ne o(n),$$
i.e., there are infinitely many $n\in\mathbb N$ for which $\tan n=\Omega(n)$. It is also known that $|x-p/q|=\Omega(q^{-2})$ for all but finitely many $(p,q)\in\mathbb N^2$ iff the coefficients of the simple continued fraction of $x$ are bounded. While (IIRC) it has not been proved, the coefficients of the simple continued fraction of $\pi$ are very likely unbounded. This would imply $\tan n\ne O(n)$, i.e., there are infinitely many $n\in\mathbb N$ for which $\tan n=\omega(n)$.

thanks for the very detailed answer! so integer restriction changed picture a lot, as I understand we're trying to still talk about asymptotic points and how close can we go there with integers and in that case we analyse behaviour of tangent (rate of growth). Also, for reals it isn't $O(2^n)$ and restriction to integers make it $O(2^n)$ right?

Yes, that's right.

A better way to understand the asymptotic behaviour of the tangent function is to understand how it behaves at various points.
Bachmann's big-oh, as we typically use it in computer science, gives the asymptotic behaviour as $x \rightarrow \infty$. But De Bruijn's big-oh can be used to represent asymptotic behaviour at any point, not just infinity.
So, for example, the tangent function has a Laurent series expansion at $x = \pi/2$:
$$\displaystyle -\frac{1}{x - \pi/2} + \frac{1}{3}\left(x - \pi/2\right) + \frac{1}{45}\left(x - \pi/2\right)^3 + \frac{2}{945}\left(x - \pi/2\right)^5 + O\left(\left(x - \pi/2\right)^7\right)$$
So in De Bruijn's notation, you could say:
$$\displaystyle \tan x = -\frac{1}{x - \pi/2} + O\left(x - \pi/2\right)\,\,\,\,\,(x \rightarrow \pi/2)$$

thanks for the answer and interesting information, I think answer by @zkutch answers my question more specifically, so I will accept as an answer that one, however since this provides interesting information regarding big O complexity of tangent, I still upvote it.

tan x = sin x / cos x
For x = (2k + 1/2) * pi - eps, sin x ≈ 1 and cos x ≈ eps, so tan x ≈ 1/eps. Pick a large k, y = (2k + 1/2) * pi, eps = 1 / (y/2 w^y), x = y - eps, then tan x ≈ x^2 2^x.
This show tan x for real x is not O(2^x).

thanks, this adds some formalism to the answer provided by @zkutch
